# How to get rid of FindBugs false positive message in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs

The code snippet in place:

```
 if (isExternal(user, task)) {
```

which outputs in 'Bug explorer'-view: 
"Nullcheck of value previously dereferenced" > "Nullcheck of user at line NNN of value previously dereferenced in same.package.class.Name"

How to switch this message off(if possible), which is currently a false positive?

Comment: It might be helpful to show more code.  It is unclear why this would be a false positive.  This message indicates a check for null after a null pointer exception would have already occurred.  If `isExternal` is checking for null, check to see that you have not already used `user` prior to this line or in the named class.  The earlier instance of user would have caused the NPE before reaching the null check.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722528/sonar-critical-violation-nullcheck-of-value-previously-dereferenced which this question may duplicate.